# The system cannot find message text for message number 0x%1 in the message file for %2

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am getting the following exception when changing opacity of the Form (from 0.0 to 1.0 on a thread using BeginInvoke() with the interval of 0.2) while loading. Getting the following exception occasionally. Any reason to get this?

> **System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find message text for message number 0x%1 in the message file for %2    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.UpdateLayered()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.set_Opacity(Double value)**

Answer (score 0):

This message itself indicates that some error occurred, but that .net was unable to translate it to a human-readable text.

You should look at the error number, or possibly the InnerException for the real exception.

Comment: This is the innermost exception. Thanks